# Evaluating a symbolic function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, evaluation, derivative, function-call

I want to find `cos(5)`. Why is this expression invalid:

```
syms x
f=sin(x)
disp(diff(f)(5))
```

The error is

```
Line: 3 Column: 12
Indexing with parentheses '()' must appear as the last operation of a valid indexing expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with symbolic variables.

It is caused by the statement `diff(f)(5)` - which is not something MATLAB **syntax** allows (as of R2019b). MATLAB interprets this as the user trying to access the 5th element of some intermediate result. If you want to know the actual value of the derivative of `f` at `x=5`, you would have to substitute the desired value of `x` (using `subs`) and convert this to some numeric format (such as `double`):

```matlab
syms x
f = sin(x)
disp(double(subs(diff(f),x,5))) % substitute x and convert to double
```

Answer (score -1):

Y = cos(x) will simply provide the cosine value of x. Or all the x.

I think in your code: 
disp(diff(f(5))) should work.